# Why is window.opener undefined in this specific version of Windows/IE?

Tags: javascript, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

My website depends on popups. Up until now I've been using `window.opener.location.reload()` to refresh the parent window, but all of a sudden my users are reporting that popups are not closing. Also, calling `window.close()` causes a "The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the tab" warning.

I've managed to reproduce this issue in Windows 8.1 Pro Preview running IE 11.0.9431.228, but the problem does *not* occur in Windows 8.1 Enterprise Evaluation and IE 11.0.9600.16438.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Why would `window.opener` not be set? All popups are opened with `window.open`.

Comment: same urls, same domains, same security zones?

Comment: Could be something with IE's "trusted sites" or "Protected Mode". Have a look here to possibly figure out a workaround: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533723%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I tried resetting the all the security settings and also cranking them all the way down. Still happens. Tried disabling Protected Mode as well. Still happens.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter And yes, same URLs and domain. Like I said, it works in other browsers, and even the same OS and major version of IE; only thing I can see that's different is the minor versions. And the fact that one is running under VirtualBox and the other under Remote Desktop, but I can't see how that changes anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a partial "solution". You can get the parent window if you give it a name first (e.g. `window.name='mainwin'`), then you can access it via:

```
if(!window.opener) window.opener = window.open('','mainwin');
```

This lets me refresh the main window, but calling `window.close()` still causes a "The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the tab" warning.

Comment: `"The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the tab warning.`" You never mentioned this in your original question...

Comment: @zyboxenterprises: No, I did not. I didn't want to overcomplicate the question. I believe that if the browser sets `window.opener` correctly then `window.close()` shouldn't cause a warning, so solving one should fix the other. And if not, that's a new question :-)

Comment: It would have probably made it a lot easier to answer the question if you had put that, lol